# Storing 2D arrays and calling them again later in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a text game in Java that uses a 2D array for a board. I want to make this so when I enter the "scan" command it will print the same 8x8 board each time. The program compiled fine I just need to know how to print the same 8x8 board I generate each time I run the "scan" command.

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        public static void Start() {
        System.out.println("Would you like a Short, Medium, or Long game?");
        String x = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Are you a Novice, Fair, Good, Expert, or Emeritus player?");
        String y = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Good Luck!");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        }
        
       public static void main() {
                //create the grid
       String x;
       String y;
       String z;

       z = in.nextLine();
        if (z.equals("scan")) {
        final int rowWidth = 8;
        final int colHeight = 8;
        Random rand = new Random();
        boolean a = true;
        boolean b = true;
        boolean c = true;
        boolean d = true;
        String [][] board = new String[rowWidth][colHeight];
        
        //fill the grid
        for (char row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            
            for (char col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                double r = Math.random();

                
                
                if(a == true && r <= .02) {
                  board[row][col] = "P";
                  a = false; }
                

                 else if(b == true && r <= .04 && r > .02){
                  board[row][col] = "K"; 
                  b = false; }
                

                else if(c == true && r <= .06 && r > .04){
                  board[row][col] = "B";  
                  c = false; }
                  
                 else if(d == true && r <= .08 && r > .06){
                  board[row][col] = " ";  
                  d = false; }
                  
                  
                  else 
                    board[row][col] = "*";
                

                }
            }
       //display output
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                    
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
                //System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("");
        z = in.nextLine();
        main();
    }else if( z.equals("exit")) {
    System.exit(0);
}else {
           System.out.println("Parton");
            main();
       }   

        }
        
        public static void run() {
            Start();
            main();
        }
        
    }//end of main

//end of class Main
```

Comment: 1) I don't see a scan command?

Comment: @blahfunk after I declare the three strings I get input. If that input equals "scan" then the 8x8 is generated.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a simple program, you can make simple changes to do this. Just widen the scope of your array to the class level and then create a scan method.

```
public class Main {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] board;

    ...//Your other code

    public static scan() {
        //Printing/Drawing logic
    }
}
```

Then you can just add a select statement for "scan" to your current input check, which would run the method.

However, when it comes to designs like this, I would prefer to have some kind of `Board` class backed by the 2D array which could contain many useful functions for the program, including `Board.scan()`, and perhaps even a helper class to resolve input strings.